# Questions that may require updating every few years

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/809/is-christianity-continuing-to-grow-worldwide?rq=1) is concerned with the growth of global Christianity. The only problem that I have with it is that the answers may need to be updated every few years or every few decades, which makes this question different from theology-based questions.

A question based on a theological position/conviction may be more constant, unless the authorities in that religion change a doctrinal position or adapt a doctrine to modern times or re-interpret the same old doctrine in new light. Until then, the same old doctrine can be assumed to be true of the whole denomination.

It would be cool if there is a function that allows users to check which questions need to be updated once in a while. Maybe one question can be flagged as "need to be updated", and other users may come in and update it.

Comment: As long as the answer dates itself, I don't see a problem. It can always be updated if/when newer info is made available.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really think anything special is needed. If such a post looks like it might be outdated then you could update it yourself if you know how, or post a bounty if you don't.

Comment: This. Considering the example question was  from 2011 and isn't out-dated yet, I think the time scale for most of the questions that are even on topic here are on the order of decades—much longer than most SE sites. In the event you run across a decades old C.SE post, a look at the date should inform readers of the need to consider how relevant the data is to their time frame.

Answer (score 3):

You could flag it for a moderator to put a "Current Event -( rapidly changing event)" post notice on it, which would indicate that the answer will change over time.

[image]

The issue is that ["current event" isn't well-defined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean/107271#107271), and we'd probably need to come up with a more solid definition for our site.

Side note, [I just proposed a change to that flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276849/proposal-modify-the-current-event-post-notice).

Comment: I think your proposed wording for that post notice is good for other reasons, but I don't think the kind of posts asked about in this question would benefit from post notices of any kind hence I don't think recommending them to be flagged is a good idea. That might be okay for breaking news stories that change as the hours go by, but the example question changes over decades, not hours. If those come up for moderator attention we'll be getting flags on every second post on this site (all the non historical ones).